# Setting _id by parsing a field in the _source document

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

Say I have documents that look like this:

```
{
  "url": "http://example.com/blog/title-of-some-blog-post",
  "author": "John Smith"
}
```

Say I have an ElasticSearch index named `blog` which has a type named `post` in it. This type holds documents like the one above. I want the `_id` of the above document to be `title-of-some-blog-post`. What should my type mapping look like?

So far, I've been able to make the `_id` the same as the `url` field but that means the `_id` also contains "http://example.com/blog/", which I wish to omit. The mapping I'm using to make this happen is:

```
"post": {
  "_id": {
    "type": "string",
    "path": "url"
  }
```

Is there some way to apply a regex to the `url` field so I can extract everything after the rightmost slash into the `_id`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box way to generate fields on the fly based on your actual fields. Although a similar feature might come in the feature, for now you just need to add a field that contains what you need, or even better provide the id outside of your documents. The latter would be better since the `_id` field is used to decide where to route your documents, and if it's part of your documents, the documents need to be parsed in order to know where they are supposed to go.